# What causes CTRL-ALT-DELETE to be enabled on a non-domain-joined system?

Tags: windows-7, security, group-policy, login-screen, ctrl-alt-delete

Recently, on my personal laptop running Windows 7, my login screen turned into a CTRL-ALT-DELETE secure login screen. I've looked around for reasons why this might be the case, and the only indication is domain group policy. However, my laptop is entirely for personal use, and is not actively (and never has) joined to a domain.

Attempts to disable this key combination requirement doesn't work, including using the standard `netplwiz` application, which grayed out the checkbox to disable secure logon. The Local Security Policy can be changed, but as it mentions...

```
Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL

This security setting determines whether pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL is required before a user can log on.
...
Default on domain-computers: Disabled.
Default on stand-alone computers: Enabled.
```

Since I am on a stand-alone computer, by default, this should be Enabled. My laptop has this setting currently set to Disabled. This confirmed my suspicions that this kind of login is NOT normal for a personal laptop, and is only for domain-based systems.

Overall, my question is this: why is this happening, and what might be causing this change? I would like to treat the cause of this issue, not the symptom.

(And yes, I understand the implications of disabling secure login, but it's kinda strange and disconcerting to have something like this change without actively changing this setting yourself.)

Comment: You are running these commands and trying to change these options as an Administrator correct?

Comment: Without more details from your end, it's impossible to speculate what happened.  That setting can be changed by anything.  You, accidentally.  A program.  A utility.  A virus/malware (though that wouldn't exactly make sense).  Simply change it back, and then, if it happens again, you can start the process of narrowing down causes.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes - `netplwiz` automatically gains administrator access, though interestingly enough it does NOT prompt me anymore for it. (This is both running with and without using "Run As Administrator".

Comment: @Nick2253 I've enabled that policy for now. I don't think it's me, because the only thing I do on this system is browse the web, edit documents, and run various programs - but never mess with any of those kind of settings, not even touching the users/password manager. The only possibilities are with the AV (Avast/HitmanPro.Alert) or the recent uninstall of several Intel utilities, which were aimed for businesses that required unified IT security/audit control.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways this could have been changed. One way to find out more details would be to review the Event Logs and see if you can pinpoint when and by what application this change was made.

The symptom can usually be fixed using this [Fix It from Microsoft](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9733466). This Fix It is for Windows XP, Vista and 7.

Detailed steps involved in the Fit It above can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308226/en-us).

Note: Please make sure to run any window that you use to fix this as Administrator

Comment: My event logs extend all the way to late 2013. How can I filter my event logs to find these changes, and which log? Assuming the security log is what I should be looking at, Google says that event 612 is for an "audit change", the closest thing I could find for a change in policy...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it don't solve your problem, just like me.

I could solve with this aproach: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/612-secure-logon-press-ctrl-alt-delete-log.html   using  OPTION THREE  -- Through Local Security Policy.

I hope it can help you too.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install mouse whitout borders recently?

May it is changing Ctrl+Alt+Del behavior, even after you change status manually.

Please let me know if you installed this or similar software.